# Does the comma category of a set over category of graphs have initial and terminal objects?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

As the question states.
Let $S$ be a set and $U : \textbf{Graph} \to \textbf{Set}$ be the forgetful functor. Then does the comma category $S \downarrow U$ have initial or terminal objects?

I think the answer is no to both questions. Every construction of an initial/terminal object that I've tried has failed for some reason or another. Maybe I'm thinking about the question in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object of $S \downarrow U$ is an $S$-pointed graph, so there definitely is an initial object: which $S$-pointed graph has a unique $S$-embedding into every graph?

> Answer: $S$ as a discrete graph with the natural $S$-pointing.

If you allow loops, there also is a terminal object: which $S$-pointed graph admits a unique $S$-homomorphism from any graph?

> Answer: $S$ as a complete graph with all edges, including all loops.

Comment: What do you mean by S as a discrete graph?

Comment: The graph with set of vertices equal to $S$ and with no edges. (I invented the word, but compare with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_category ) You may also want to call it the _free graph_ on $S$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object

Comment: Let's say that we define the category of graphs so that the edge set must be reflexive i.e. every vertex has an edge to itself. I think the edge set of the initial object would then change to $\{(a, a) : a \in S \}$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that's right. That would make more sense, if you view a graph as a category (so that it has identity maps).